# Double type with custom comparation in Scala

Tags: scala, wrapper

I'm migrating some old Java code to Scala which uses a "precision" threshold for comparing real values. A fragment of the already translated to Scala code would be:

```
object CompareDouble {
  private val EPSILON = 0.00001

  def equals(a: Double, b: Double): Boolean = a == b || Math.abs(a - b) < EPSILON

  def greater(a: Double, b: Double): Boolean = a - b > EPSILON
  .
  .
  .
}
```

The problem with this code is that it's usage gets easily verbose, for instance:

```
  //In an interval overlap comparison
        CompareDouble.lessEquals(low1, low2) && CompareDouble.lessEquals(low2, up1) ||
          CompareDouble.lessEquals(low1, up2) && CompareDouble.lessEquals(up2, up1) ||
          CompareDouble.lessEquals(low2, low1) && CompareDouble.lessEquals(low1, up2) ||
          CompareDouble.lessEquals(low2, up1) && CompareDouble.lessEquals(up1, up2)
```

So I was trying to define some sort of wrapper class for the value that would allow me to use the standard operators. The idea is to be able to do:

```
  //Just an example of the idea
  if a == b then...
  else if a > b then...
```

Where `a == b` would be the original `def equals(a: Double, b: Double):` and so on

So far, I've done this:

```
class PrecisionDouble(var wrapp: Double) {
  // PrecissionDouble.EPSILON refers to a field in this class' companion object
  def == (that: PrecisionDouble): Boolean = wrapp == that.wrapp || Math.abs(wrapp - that.wrapp) < PrecisionDouble.EPSILON

  def < (that: PrecisionDouble): Boolean = (that.wrapp - wrapp) > PrecisionDouble.EPSILON
```

which works for the comparison use case, but I must manually wrapp and unwrapp the value within the class for other usages (such as math functions or basic aritmethics). I would like to achieve this:

```
  val a = PrecisionDouble(3.2)
  val b: Double = math.sqrt(a)
```

and also be able to replace the type of the parameters in the PrecisionDouble comparison methods from `def == (that: PrecisionDouble)` to `def == (that: Double)` to be able to do the comparisons even less verbosely.

Is this somehow possible?

Edit: Scala 3.2

Comment: Scala 2 or Scala 3?

Comment: Note that this is something interesting to implement by yourself but you could maybe take the opportunity to not use `Double` in the 1st place but `BigDecimal` with a fixed precision.

Comment: Check edit. BigDecimal wouldn't use more memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to add new comparison operators in Scala 3:

```
extension (d: Double)
    def === (other: Double) = CompareDouble.equals(d, other)
    def >> (other: Double) = CompareDouble.greater(d, other)
```

You can use `CrossVersion.for2_13Use3` in `sbt` if you need to use this in a Scala 2 project.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is probably to use a different set of operators:

```
object Precision { 
   implicit class D(val d: Double) extends AnyVal { 
     def === (other: Double) = CompareDouble.equals(d, other)
     def >> (other: Double) = CompareDouble.grater(d, other)
     // etc.
   }
}

import Precision._

println (1.41 === math.sqrt(2))
```

Alternatively, you could define implicit conversions between `Double` and `PrecisionDouble`, but I think, it is inferior, because, if operators are the same, the conversions will not happen automatically in most cases anyway.

Comment: Good idea to define new operators, but OP has now indicated that this is Scala 3 so should be `extension` rather than `implicit class`.

Comment: This works fine in scala 3 as is. Personally, I am not a fan of playing with language syntax between versions just for the sake of playing with syntax ... So, I'll live converting this to a fancier style that doesn't compile in earlier versions as an exercise for the reader :D